# My project with Kal in a workspace: thinks Kal is the primary target

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I looked at all of the prior answers in SO for an answer to this question:  I have created a workspace, added Kal and *then* added a NEW project, an empty tab bar application.  Both *build* successfully; but when I try to do a run on my project, nothing happens (the "bong" from pressing an invalid key occurs), like it's not eligible to be run!

Q1:  Do I have to create the workspace, *then add MY project*, then add Kal?  Or is there a setting to indicate that my project depends on Kal, therefore my project is the main project? (When I try to add Kal as a dependency to my project, nothing shows up in the pop-up window).

Q2:  Because this is a workspace, I understand that XCode takes care of the linker settings; do I still have to make all the changes to the search paths, as indicated in the Kal docs?

Here is what my scheme looks like:
[image: project scheme]

Comment: What does your scheme look like when encountering this?

Comment: What "scheme" are you referring to?

Comment: In the top left corner of Xcode clicking the button with your project's title adjacent to the build/run and stop button will open up the scheme selector. If you're in a workspace it is normal that your projects have separate schemes.

Comment: Updated question to show scheme... hope that's what you're looking for...

Comment: Not exactly but by the cut off word "Kal" where I was talking about I can see that "Kal" is the active target. On the right of the stop button and the left of "iPad 5.1 Simulator" try clicking "Kal" and seeing is Soari is an option for a scheme.

Comment: No, it is not... how do I change that? (it's not to early to start all over again, if that is the best choice) :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12273/discussion-between-ipwnstuff-and-spokane-dude)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using "⌘ + shift + ."(⌘ + <) followed by pressing "Manage Schemes…" in the left of the popup that appears then pressing the + above "Edit…" in the new popup in the next popup(**geez!**) hit the picker next to target select Soari under the Soari.xcodeproj and naming it whatever you like. Next in the top left corner of Xcode clicking the button with your project's title adjacent to the build/run and stop button will open up the scheme selector. If you're in a workspace it is normal that your projects have separate schemes but adding it should've fixed that.